# How to add .Net framework 4.6.1 Class Library instead of .Net standard in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'am very new in Visual Studio 2017 and I really need a help. I have a solution and i need to add new .Framework 4.6.1 Class Library into this solution. I can't see classic .Net Framework class library, only .Net standard. Please, help me, how can I achieve that?

Comment: What helped me was this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51193911/15104639

Answer (score 7):

It should be an option in the "Windows Desktop" group when adding a new project.

[image]

Make sure you have the components for .NET Framework 4.6.1 development installed using the Visual Studio Installer tool.

[image]

Comment: thanks it worked for me, i spend hours to find this :)