# Select framework version for .NET Core Class Library project - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-class-library

In Visual Studio 2019 if I try to create an ASP.NET Core web application project, I get to select the framework version in the following screen -

[image]

But when I try to create a .NET Core class library project I am prompted with  the following screen which does not provide any option for selecting the framework version -

[image]

Clicking the Create button always creates the project right away taking the latest .NET Core version installed on my machine.

So, how can I select the framework version while creating the class library project? Or do I have to change it manually every time after creation ?

Comment: It seems you have VS 2019 **Preview** installed. Otherwise .Net Core 3.0 won't be in your list. Have you tried to download not preview version and check there?

Comment: @OlegI, The VS is "not preview" version, and I have installed .Net Core 3.0 Preview 7 myself.

Comment: Ensure you allow usage of preview .NET Core versions in `Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features` if you want to use them. You then change the project version by editing the `TargetFramework(s)` element of the csproj. You can also right-click the project, choose Properties, and select another `Target Framework` from the combo box if you prefer this UI, but editing the csproj instead has become a well-defined developer task with .NET Core.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193853/how-can-i-change-a-net-standard-library-to-a-net-framework-library

Comment: @RayKoopa, I know how to manually change framework version. Previous versions of VS had an option to select framework version when you are selecting a Class Library template, for both .NET Framework and .NET Core. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @atiyar It's gone with the new project dialog in VS2019. The listed options in my answer are the current ones.

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET project creation dialog providing a framework selection seems to be an exception in .NET Core / Standard projects to me. At least since VS2019 with the new "New Project" dialog, you have the following options *after* creating the project with this dialog.

"Normally" (to my experience), you right-click the project file in the Solution Explorer, choose "Edit Project File" and modify the `<TargetFramework>` element by naming one of the valid target framework monikers. [See MSDN about them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks).

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

You can also rename the element to `TargetFrameworks` (note the pluralized name) to build against multiple frameworks at the same time, which are `;` separated:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net451;netstandard2.0;netcoreapp3.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Alternatively, you can also choose "Properties" from the project right-click menu and select a framework via a slightly dated UI not supporting all of the new csproj features, like said multi targeting:

[image: Project properties]

If you need many new projects building against a specific framework, create a template csproj and just copy and rename it.

Also, if you want to build against preview versions of .NET Core in non-preview versions of VS, ensure you allow usage of them in `Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features`.